# Prove that addition is associative with respect to this ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I'm having trouble with this task:

> We can identify the Boolean algebra of propositions with the Boolean ring $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z,+,·)$ (so, this set has two operations: addition and multiplication - but they’re not the usual ones!)  by defining $\neg x:= 1 +x,x∨y:=x+y+x·y,$ and $x\land y:=x·y$, where all arithmetic occurs modulo $2$.  It’s not difficult to verify that negation and conjunction so defined are associative operations,  however, addition is another matter.  Prove that addition so defined is associative.

Associativity means that $a + (b + c) = (b+c)+a$. I'm guessing it wants me to prove that $x + y$ is associative.

Does it want me to use the definition of $x\lor y$ to prove this? Then I suppose I would have to prove $x\lor y=(x+y)+xy$ and $x\lor y=xy+(x+y)$. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Doesn't associativity involve three distinct elements from the base set?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Good point. How do I get these three distinct elements and where do I go from there?

Comment: Addition and multiplication modulo 2 ***are*** the "usual" operations on $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ -- and if those operations are what is meant, associativity is automatic because a quotient ring is a ring. What operations do they mean if you're not supposed to use the usual ones?

Comment: Are you defining new binary operations on a field and then asking if they are associative?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I don't think so... This is the full statement of the exercise and I'm not entirely sure what it's asking.

Comment: Sorry...I forgot about the Boolean ring.

Comment: What the heck?  "Prove that addition so defined is associative."  Addition HOW defined?  Addition was never defined? And how can negation be associative if it is a unitary operation?  .... Okay, I think there are saying.  $x\land y = x\cdot y$ is multiplication and is easy to see is associative (it's modulo arithmetic).  I thin if the new addition is $x \lor y = x+y + x\cdot y$ and you must prove that is associative.  I.e. that $x + (y+z + y\cdot z) = (x + y + x\cdot y) + z +  (x + y + x\cdot y)\cdot z$.

Comment: @fleablood You confused me at the end there. Where does $z$ come from? And where does $x+(y+z+y⋅z)$ and $z+(x+y+x⋅y)⋅z$ come from?

Comment: You need to prove $x \lor (y \lor z) = (x\lor y)\lor z$. And $x \lor (y\lor z) = x + (y+z + y\cdot z) + x\cdot(y+z + y\cdot z)$ and $(x\lor y) \lor z = (x+y + x\cdot y) + z + (x+y+x\cdot y)\cdot z$.

Comment: @fleablood Okay. Got it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the original problem has a typo and that it intended to say that it is easy to prove that $x\wedge y$ is associative, but you are being asked to prove that $x \vee y$ is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guy must have been falling asleep when he wrote this.  Or drunk.

I can only assume (and I could be dead wrong)

That he is defining

Addition = $\lor$, which is defined by $x \lor y = x + y + x\cdot y$.

Multiplication = $\land$ which is defined by $x \land y = x \land y$.

(I have the slightest idea why the #### he brought up negation, which being a unary and not binary operation can't be associative.)

$\land$ is just modulo multiplication so of course it is associative.

But $\lor$ is not so obvious.  I'm assuming that is what you must prove is associative. i.e. that $x\lor (y \lor z) = (x\lor y)\lor z$.

Comment: These are notes from a lecture so I guess there are some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is to prove that $\vee$ is associative (calling it “addition” is not really being gentle to the poor student); it's actually quite easy:
\begin{align}
x\vee(y\vee z)
&=x\vee(y+z+yz)\\
&=x+(y+z+yz)+x(y+z+yz)\\
&=x+y+z+yz+xy+xz+xyz
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(x\vee y)\vee z
&=(x+y+xy)\vee z\\
&=x+y+xy+z+(x+y+xy)z\\
&=x+y+xy+z+xz+yz+xyz
\end{align}
The two final terms are equal.

Answer (score 1):

hint: the OP seems to be making two mistakes in his attack of the problem.
1.  As Michael McGovern suggested, you need to determine whether for all values x,y,z, does (xVy)Vz = xV(yVz).
2.  If I understand the problem correctly, x,y,z are all in $\{0,1\}.$  Therefore, there are only 2x2x2 = 8 possible combinations to check.  Checking all 8, you will either find a counter example or demonstrate universal associativity.

The problem may have intended that you strive for a "step back" insight.  Examining the 2x2 = 4 combinations of x,y, which of the 4 combinations yields xVy = 0.  Can you immediately intuit precisely when (for example) (((aVb)Vc)Vd)Ve will equal 0?  If so, can you use that intuition to form a rule that will immediately resolve whether the operation is associative?  Note that by definition, the operation is commutative.